# changing an array element of json in array is changing the rest json array elements in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-copy

this is the array variable

```
let packageitems=

    [
      {  
      "packageid":1,

      "items":[  
         {  
            "itemid":"1",
            "name":"abc"
         },
         {  
            "itemid":"2",
            "name":"cdr"
         }
      ]
     },
     {  
      "packageid":2,
      "items":[  
         {  
            "itemid":"1",
            "name":"abc"
         },
         {  
            "itemid":"2",
            "name":"xyz"
         }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

in angular typescript i am having one function:

```
updatePackageitem(newitem){
    let objIndex = this.packageitems.findIndex(obj => obj.packageid==newitem.packageid);
    Object.assign(this.packageitems[objIndex] , newitem);
}
```

`newitem` json is similar just the items array is different
when i assign using Object.assign the `newitem` array elements get copies to all rest json of `this.packageitems` even after getting the `objIndex` right

```
newitem =

      {  
      "packageid":2,
      "items":[  
         {  
            "itemid":"1",
            "name":"def"
         },
         {  
            "itemid":"2",
            "name":"pqr"
         }
      ]
     }
```

Comment: don't use find for updated. use loops.

Comment: tried traditional way of using loops and finding by if condition but still it changes other json of that array